# Face appears on printed writing when viewed from a distance

Tags: story-identification, tv

Can someone remember the 90s episode where the detectives find a room with printed papers all over the floor and, when they view these papers from a gallery above, a low resolution face could be seen?

I think it was in the X-Files, and I think the papers were printed with zeros and ones.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Other than your impression that this might be X-Files, were there any SF elements?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"[Conduit](https://x-files.fandom.com/wiki/Conduit)", indeed from *X-Files*

> They return to the Morris house, which is empty, with the front door unlocked and many sheets of paper laid out on the lounge floor. The papers are covered in neatly written binary strings, Scully looks at the arrangement from the mezzanine level above the lounge and from this new perspective sees the chilling image of Ruby Morris' face made up from 1's and 0's.

[image: Image of Ruby Morris's face, formed from papers on the floor covered in binary strings]

Comment: Ahh, dot-matrix image art. Those were the days.